# Can't switch language environment in Django

Tags: django, internationalization

I have file locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo (and .po), ran makemessages and compilemessages. Definitely all messages are translated

in settings.py have:

```
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

Still django stubbornly takes strings from the english .po file... Why can that be?

There must be some gotcha... Thanks.

**EDIT** this appears to be the case only when LocaleMiddleware is active.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the django docs

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#id2

> LocaleMiddleware tries to determine
>   the user's language preference by
>   following this algorithm:
>
> ```
> * First, it looks for a django_language key in the current user's session.
>
> * Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> *Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by priority. Django > tries each language in the header  until it finds one with available translations.
>
> * Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.
> ```

If you only need one language, 'es', you can disable the middleware.
If you really need LocaleMiddleware active, try this recipe to override the headers from the client's browser http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/218/:

```
enter code here

class ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware(object):
    """
    Ignore Accept-Language HTTP headers

    This will force the I18N machinery to always choose settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
    as the default initial language, unless another one is set via sessions or cookies

    Should be installed *before* any middleware that checks    request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],
    namely django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'):
            del request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

Comment: For those using Python 3.X, `if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'):` needs to be changed to `if 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' in request.META:`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my settings :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
```

So you should use something like 'es-ES'